# Showing that $\mathbb{C}$ under the lexicographic order does not satisfy $x,y>0\implies xy>0$

Tags: order-theory

Identifying $\mathbb{C}$ with $\mathbb{R} \times \mathbb{R}$, we can consider the lexicographic order: we define $x_1 + iy_1 < x_2 +iy_2$ if either

A) $x_1 < x_2$ or B) $x_1 = x_2$ and $y_1 < y_2$.

Prove that this relation does not satisfy Axiom 8 of Apostles chapter.

where Axiom 8 states If $x > 0$ and $y > 0$, then $xy > 0$

I don't know how to go about this question, yeah I understand what we were defined on the complex line. But I don't know how to relate this to axiom 8. Please help out, thank you.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

HINT: $0<i$; what about $i^2$?

Comment: and $i^2$ > 0 but how would i apply a and b into this question

Comment: @MathGeek: $i^2=-1$ is **not** greater than $0$.

Comment: sorry that is what I meant i forgot to read over my comment

Comment: so are you saying let x=i and y=$i^2$ ? then xy < 0 ? and this relation wont satisfy axiom 8?

Comment: @MathGeek: No, I’m suggesting that you take $x=y=i$.

Comment: Yes I understand that, but notice we are given conditions A and then B where does that come into play.

Comment: @MathGeek: Those aren’t conditions; they are the two cases defining the linear order on $\Bbb C$. The comparison of $0=0+0i$ and $i=0+1\cdot i$ falls under case (B): $0=0$ in the real part, and $0<1$ in the imaginary part, so $0<i$. The comparison of $i^2=-1$ and $0$, on the other hand, falls under case (A): the real part of $-1$ is $-1$, which is smaller than $0$, the real part of $0$.